# Getting error: "Error: Function PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula" on following formula

Tags: formula

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "deprioritized") && (PRIORVALUE (StageName) <> "deprioritized"),
    TRUE,
    FALSE
)
```

**not sure if the above or bottom formula works - but point still holds*

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Deprioritized"), 
    null,
    IF(PRIORVALUE(StageName) = "Deprioritized", 
        null,
        TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName)) & " - " & StageName
    )
)
```

Context: I have a opportunity history report that shows funnel movement. We have a stage called "deprioritized" and we don't want to show a deal's funnel movement if the current stage that it's in is "de-prioritized".

Which means - if there was an Opportunity that went from First Meeting into De-prioritized - it technically goes through a stage called 2nd meeting.

We don't want to show ANY funnel movement for that Opportunity.

Comment: Quick note on the first formula: `IF(<condition>, true, false)` can _always_ be simplified to `<condition>`. The condition in an IF statement already returns a boolean (true/false) result. There's no need to wrap that in an IF.

Comment: @DerekF- that's helpful, but do you know the answer to my question overall?

Answer (score 0):

PRIORVALUE only works when the record is currently being modified. Validation Rules, Workflow Rules, Record-Triggered Flows, those kinds of things. For a report, you can't use PRIORVALUE, because you're not currently in a DML transaction. I don't think there's a way to get this kind of report, it might involve some kind of code or flow to build the data the way you want it to be shown in the report.